# Why aren't my divs tags showing up?

Tags: html, css

This is my first post here on so please excuse my formatting if it's incorrect. I am building a project and I'm having trouble with my divs. In my project I am unable to make my divs show up with their css style. The blank space is there where they are supposed to be but the div (cards) are supposed to be yellow with a black border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Memory Card Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Memory Game</h1>
  <nav a="#"><h2>Instructions</h2></nav>
  <nav a="Game">Game</nav>
  <p>Concentration, also known as Match Match, Memory, Pelmanism, Shinkei-suijaku, Pexeso, or Pairs, is a card game in which all of the cards are laid facedown on a surface and two cards are flipped face up over each turn. The object of the game is to turn over pairs of matching cards.</p>
  <div class="board">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div> 
  </div>

  <footer>Created with ♥ by <span class="name">GA</span></footer>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



h1 {
    color: rgb(2, 132, 130);
}
h2 {
    color: #ffd700;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

.board {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.name {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

update of what my changes did:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipyPW.jpg

Below are screen shots of what my page is doing and what its supposed to look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mca89.jpg

Comment: How can we possibly tell from an image? Post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Change `color: black` to `background-color:black`. But don't you want to use yellow? The cards in the image are yellow.

Comment: Thanks your help, my updates have the background yellow but the cards are still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the css as below

```
  h1 {
color: rgb(2, 132, 130);
   }
h2 {
color: #ffd700;
 }

body {
text-align: left;
}

.board {
display: inline-block;
height: 80%;
width: 50%;
color: yellow;
}
.card {
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
border:solid 1px black;
border-radius: 10px;
color: black;
background-color:yellow;
 }
.name {
color: #ff0000;
}
```

pls check the screenshot of mine http://prntscr.com/db2se1

Answer (score -2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" style.css">
```

Replace your link with this

Comment: How does adding a space to the file name resolve any of this?